# Insert into mysql without internet

Tags: android

I'm working on an android application that inserts a list and some editTexts into an online database (mySql). Later I realized that the application will be used in areas where there is no internet! I want it when I don't have internet and I press the insert button to "run" until it has internet. how can i do this?... any other ideas?

Comment: Store the query, check for internet connectivity before attempting to execute the query. Once the user has regained internet, run all the stored queries.

Answer (score 0):

yes. first you create local database like sqlite. Check app connected to internet or not using background service. if your app connected to internet, directly send data to online mysql database.otherwise you can store data to sqlite and when your app connected to internet push it to mysql.